# Performance tuning: string wordcount in df

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a df with column "free text". I wish to count how many characters and words each cell has.
Currently, I do it like this:

```
d = {'free text': ["merry had a little lamb", "Little Jonathan found a chicken"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Chars'] = df['free text'].apply(str).apply(len)
df['Words'] = df['free text'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split()))
```

Problem is, that it is pretty slow. I thought about using `np.where` but I wasn't sure how.
Would appreciate your help here.

Comment: can you pls provide sample dataframe and expected output from it?

Comment: Sure, editing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

you can try via `str.len()` and `str.count()`:

```
df['Chars'] = df['free text'].str.len()
df['Words'] = df['free text'].str.count(' ')+1
```

Sample dataframe used:

```
d = {'free text': ["merry had a little lamb", "Little Jonathan found a chicken",np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

OR

via numpy but you will get 0 count when there are NaN's present:

```
df['Chars'] =np.char.count(df['free text'].to_numpy(na_value='').astype(str),' ')
df['Words'] =np.char.str_len(df['free text'].to_numpy(na_value='').astype(str))
```

output of `df`:

```
    free text                           Chars   Words
0   merry had a little lamb             23.0    5.0
1   Little Jonathan found a chicken     31.0    5.0
2   NaN                                 NaN     NaN
```

Comment: for ```df['Words']```, wouldn't it count na values as one word?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel nope NaN remains NaN